# How setup dart objectbox with a local database pre-populated?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox, objectbuilder

I want to set up an ObjectBox database with Flutter.
I would like to pre-populate the database file with values. When installing the application, the database file will be copied and is used by the application. I want to be able to continue to provide schema migrations. Is it possible?

How to set up this type of architecture?
Have you any example?

**SOLUTION** :
With @vaind response, I have implemented a database Manager like :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import '../objectbox.g.dart';

/// Database manager manage database initialisation and configuration.
class DatabaseManager {
  static DatabaseManager? _instance;

  DatabaseManager._internal();

  /// Singleton Factory constructor
  factory DatabaseManager() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = DatabaseManager._internal();
    }

    return _instance!;
  }

  /// Initialize configuration of database:
  ///  - Init database file by copying.
  ///  - Open instance of database and close it.
  Future<void> init() async {
    await copyDatabaseFileFromAssets();
    await testInstanceAndCloseIt();
  }

  /// Copy packaged database from the assets folder to the app directory.
  Future<void> copyDatabaseFileFromAssets() async {
    // Get a pre-populated DB file.
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/databases/data.mdb");
    List<int> bytes =
    data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

    // Search and create DB file destination folder if not exist
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = documentsDirectory.path + "/objectbox/data.mdb";

    if (!await File(path).exists()) {
      var objectBoxDirectory = Directory(documentsDirectory.path + "/objectbox/");
      if ((!await objectBoxDirectory.exists())) {
        objectBoxDirectory.create();
      }

      // Copying source data into destination file.
      await new File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes);
    }
  }

  /// Open an instance of the database and close it.
  Future<void> testInstanceAndCloseIt() async {
    await openStore().then((Store store) {
      store.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, even if you want to avoid populating the database in-app (e.g. on the first run), you can bundle an existing database. Just create the database file (`data.mdb`) locally, even on your machine (they're compatible across platforms) and than add it to the app as a resource.

On the first app run you can then just move the `data.mdb` file to the application documents directory (into subdirectory `objectbox`) - that's where ObjectBox stores the by default if you've used the generated `openStore()` method. So the path to the database file should be (using package `path_provider`):
`(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path + '/objectbox/data.mdb'`. Make sure you open the store **after** you write the file, of course.

---

Update after the question has been updated. I think your `copyDatabaseFileFromAssets` should look more like the following. Create the database file only if it doesn't exist.

```dart
Future<void> copyDatabaseFileFromAssets() async {
  // Search and create db file destination folder if not exist
  final documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final objectBoxDirectory = Directory(documentsDirectory.path + '/objectbox/');
  
  if (!objectBoxDirectory.existsSync()) {
    await objectBoxDirectory.create(recursive: true);
  }

  final dbFile = File(objectBoxDirectory.path + '/data.mdb');
  if (!dbFile.existsSync()) {
    // Get pre-populated db file.
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/databases/data.mdb");

    // Copying source data into destination file.
    await dbFile.writeAsBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
}
```

Comment: One suggestion, Kindly create some examples of joining complex queries. I also want to create some examples which can be useful to newbies.

Comment: PRs with examples are very welcome. I assume you've already seen [relation link queries](https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#add-query-conditions-for-related-entities-links).

Comment: Tkank's, I update my post with my implementation. How I can migrate database with this methode ?