# Flutter offline database

Tags: database, flutter, offline, objectbox

I am beginner in python and Flutter (4 months that i actually code) self-taught . There is a lot of information and I am facing a problem. I don't know how to go about it.

I am building a dictionary app in Flutter. I extracted all the words and definitions from the French Wiktionary with Scrapy and I processed all the data with pyspark. All data was inserted into an ObjectBox database with python and which has a final size of 460 mb for 355,000 elements. I compressed it with Brotli and its final size is 65 mb. So I end up with a compress mdb file. And now I'm stuck.

I thought of extracting the database to read it live with ObjectBox in Flutter but it does not read the mdb files directly and it gets complicated, I can't find any documentation on the subject. Moreover I tell myself that if the live extraction is not done on the internal memory, it will reserve ram? (If I understood correctly) This will not lead to a crash?

Or is it possible to extract it when installing the App so that objectBox can read it directly?

Or maybe I'm scratching my head over nothing. Directly read a Json but I'm afraid that the queries will be long because the word search is live for the user That this one writes a letter, my program must return me the words beginning with this one.

What would you do to maximize performance in the background  ? Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

welcome on StackOverflow! :)

I think your question is a duplicate of this one:
[How setup dart objectbox with a local database pre-populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68453004/how-setup-dart-objectbox-with-a-local-database-pre-populated)

as long as you refer to [this NoSQL](https://objectbox.io/) database by ObjectBox in both python and flutter and you're trying to use [this package](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-python) in the former and [this](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/tree/main/objectbox) in the latter.

Is that the case? Does the answer on the other question help you? If not, can you pls. elaborate what's missing/failing?

In general if you add a few links/references + narrow down the number of things/topics you ask might help (you can ask follow-up questions in comments later on answers or just post a new question if you still need infos). Not that I'm a pro here, could just make it easier for others to answer IMHO.

Comment: Hello ezmegy,

Thank you very much for your answer.

Indeed, I abandoned this project a few months ago, I moved on to something else.

I'm really sorry for not having answered you before, it's rude of me.

I wish you a very good continuation and thank you again.